# Odd random number in range [1..99]

Tags: c++, random

I want to fill an array with odd random numbers in a range [1..99].

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
using namespace std;

const int N = 100;
int a[N];

void print(){
    for (int i=0; i<N; i++) 
        cout << a[i] << " ";
}

int main(){
    srand(time(NULL));
    int number;
    for (int i=0; i<N; i++) {
        number=(rand()%100)+1;
        if (number%2!=0)
            a[i]=number;
    }
    print();
}
```

When I use this code I receive:

0 7 0 0 29 0 0 93 0 0 29 0 27 0 0 13 35 0 0 0 0 0 51 0 0 0 97 99 15 73             79 0 73 0 21 39 0 7 25 41 1 99 31 0 0 1 0 81 69 73 37 95 0 0 0 41 21 75 97 31 0 0 0 0 0 0 31 21 0 11 33 65 0 69 0 0 9 63 27 0 13 0 63 27 0 7 0 0 99 0 77 0 59 5 0 99 0 69 0 0

What is wrong with that? Why there are a lot of "0"?

Comment: The right tool to solve such problems is your debugger. You should step through your code line-by-line *before* asking on Stack Overflow. For more help, please read [How to debug small programs (by Eric Lippert)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). At a minimum, you should \[edit] your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example that reproduces your problem, along with the observations you made in the debugger.

Comment: Hint: Don't increment `i` when the random number is even.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why shouldn't there be? You only fill in odd ones:

```
    if (number%2!=0)
        a[i]=number;
```

If the random number is even, skip adding it to the array. So... every `0` you got represents an even number.

Comment: I guess then even ones should have been the garbage values. But since it is global array, values are zero. Another question is that : why do I see continuous series of numbers? In case if it would be an even/odd issue, answer would have been number, 0, number, 0 and so on.

Comment: In this case the `a` is a global.

Comment: Ok, it was a silly question. Shame on me. All I need to add is "else i--".

Comment: why even bother with the if? If you want random ODD numbers, then generate numbers `(rand(0,49)*2) + 1`, or put the random generation in a `while(!odd) { make number}`-type loop. you shouldn't mess with loop values INSIDE the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this instead where it only increments if you actually get an odd number.

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <time.h>
    using namespace std;

    const int N = 100;
    int a[N];

void print(){
    for (int i=0; i<N; i++) 
        cout << a[i] << " ";
}

    int main(){
        srand(time(NULL));
        int number;
        for (int i=0; i<N; ) {
            number=(rand()%100)+1;
            if (number%2!=0)
          {
                a[i]=number;
            i++;
          }
        }
        print();
    }
```

Comment: I say its better / cleaner to not increment on even and then decrement.

Comment: @drescherjm I agree.